# Is it really much helpful for users to provide them multiple options to sign-up or sign-in?

Tags: forms, interaction-design, login, social

I had created account on a website some months ago and today to wanted to login again but I now I don't remember which method I had used first time to create account.

[image]

If I would try the option which I did not use at first time it could create new account or I will have to try all option one by one to find which one I used.

It can take time and I might not try all option and decide to not to login (If I'm in hurry).

I realised that this would have happened with many other people too. So re-thinking on it again that whether we should give too much option to start or few?

Comment: Here on Stack Exchange, if you request your password after using external services to log in, you will be sent an e-mail telling you what service you used to sign up, and to look for the password you used for that service. Maybe they do it too?

Answer (score 4):

I would say no, many options are good.

**You want to make it easy for people to join**

The main idea behind providing multiple options is to make it easy for people to join, and you cannot expect everybody to have an account on the platform you choose as most important.

Most people will not choose a random platform to sign up, but will choose the same platform for every website they register on, so they will remember which one they used (or at least have a pretty good idea).

**Retain Users**

I think that getting users to sign up in the first place is more important than worrying about losing users because they cannot remember the service they signed up with (hopefully, they are already invested enough at that point to try some login options).

But some solutions to this might be:

- include the option in newsletters: If the website sends out newsletters, add a login button with a link to the correct signup option.
- make the popular options more visible: You can see an example for this right here at StackExchange: Google, Facebook and StackExchange have a big button, the less commonly used options have small buttons which are displayed after clicking "More login options".
- forgot password option which sends correct login option: as @DJDavid98 pointed out in the comments, you can send the user the correct login option when they click on "Forgot your password".

Comment: Agree fully. I'd add that I just had this happen today, where I couldn't remember how I registered. Most sites with multiple authentication methods do not say how you registered if you've forgotten your login, and most also auto-register on sign-in-via-social-media-tool. So it's a timesuck.

Answer (score 3):

I see your point Jitendra. I do that a lot, revisit a site I signed up for a long time ago and can't remember what service I used to sign in with.

At the same time, its better to get someone to signup initially and whatever it takes to make that easier is probably the way to go.

Plus, if a user forgot what they signup up with they probably aren't that active of a user.

Check to see if you have lots of duplicate users. If it really is a problem you might want to test different signup screens, maybe make the most popular service the most prominent and make 2-3 of the other ones less prominent.